# restrore CuDNNLSTM to CudnnCompatibleLSTM to infer on CPU using Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, inference

I am trying to use weight trained on CuDNNLSTM to infer on CPU using CudnnCompatibleLSTM, but I am unable to find the `CudnnCompatibleLSTM` layer in TF2.0. I tried doing

- `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleLSTM`
- `from tensorflow.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell import CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell`
- `from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell`

Where I can find the `CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell` or How to use the weight trained on CuDNNLSTM (on GPU) to infer it on plain LSTM (or on CPU).

I am using TF: '2.5.0-dev20201203' version.

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras.layers.LSTM``` ?

Comment: Then model trained `CuDNNLSTM` is not compatible with `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` while using CPU for inference.

Comment: So you should transfer your code to fit the new tensorflow version ......